# Accessing the Table Header

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of the table header of the current cell but i do not get any output

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){
    var thText = $(this).siblings('th').first().text();
});
```

What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Vq3av/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hPc4F/)</kbd>

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var thText = $(this).closest('tbody').prev().find('th').first().text();
    console.log(thText);
});
```

---

`table` body is stored in `tbody` and header tags in `thead`.

you need to find the closest `tbody` of the `td` and than get previous `thead` tag and than find `th`

---

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hPc4F/1)</kbd>

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var thText = $(this).closest('tbody').prev().find('th').eq(index).text();
    console.log(thText);
});
```

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: @user3315887 yes i am updating answer just wait some time

Comment: There's a lot of method chaining, so I want to what does $(this).closest('tbody') do and then what does .prev().find('th').first() do?

Comment: `prev` find previous tag of  `tbody` that is `thead` and than u find `th` in it and than select `first` of all `th`

Comment: For any cell click, your code returns Col1. Do you need to remove first()?

Comment: @user3315887 check updated answer with all links to learn  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the index of the column to match the th.

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){
    var thText = $(target).find("th").eq($(this).index()).text();
    console.log(thText);
});
```

Comment: What does this do eq($(this).index())? What is $(this) here?

Comment: also what's $(target)?

Comment: $(this) is the td that was clicked, in a list of elements like th eq(1) grabs the one in position 1 like an array.

Comment: $(target) is the same as $("#target") which is the id of the table.